# How to setup MockMvc so test don't affect each other

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing, mockmvc

I'm setting up an integrationtest to check wether the spring application works at the controller level, next to my unit test. I do know that what I am testing works, the unit tests works and I already did everyting with postman. Every integrationtest also works separatly and gives the result I expect it to give. The problem is when I run them all togheter, some tests don't work anymore. This is because the MockMvc should be'renewed' every test, but it is not.

I tried getting this behaviour by setting up the mockMvc manually with a beforeEach instead of injecting it in the constructor, but the same behaviour persist. I guess I am setting up the MockMvc wrong, but I can't seem to figure out how to set it up right. I am using Spring Boot 3 and Java 20.

How should I create the mock, so that it runs again every test, and it doesn't get affected by other tests executed? I put the testclass below.

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class EmployeeControllorIntegrationTest {

    private final static String URI = "/employees/";
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    public EmployeeControllorIntegrationTest(MockMvc mockMvc, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.mockMvc = mockMvc;
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }


    @Test
    void getAllEmployeesThrowsExceptionWhenEmpty() throws Exception{
        String error = mockMvc.perform(get(URI+"showAll"))
                .andExpect(status().isAccepted())
                .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json"))
                .andReturn().getResolvedException().getMessage();

        assertThat(error).isEqualTo("No employees present");
    }
    @Test
    void getAllEmployeesWorksWhenEmployeesPresent() throws Exception{
        this.insertUnitAndLevel();
        EmployeeDto employeeDto = new EmployeeDto("employeeName", "employeeNameSurname", LocalDate.of(2000,04,23),1L,1L);


        mockMvc.perform(post(URI+"addEmployee")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(employeeDto)));

        MockHttpServletResponse response = mockMvc.perform(get(URI+"showAll"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json"))
                .andReturn().getResponse();

        Employee[] allLevels = objectMapper.readValue(response.getContentAsString(), Employee[].class);

        assertThat(allLevels).hasSize(1);
        assertThat(Arrays.stream(allLevels).findFirst().get().getName()).isEqualTo("employeeName");
        assertThat(Arrays.stream(allLevels).findAny().get().getName()).isEqualTo("employeeName");
        assertThat(Arrays.stream(allLevels).findFirst().get().getStartDateContract()).isEqualTo(LocalDate.now());
        assertThat(Arrays.stream(allLevels).findAny().get().getStartDateContract()).isEqualTo(LocalDate.now());
    }


    @Test
    void addNewEmployeeWithInvalidNameThrowsError() throws Exception{
        this.insertUnitAndLevel();
        EmployeeDto employeeDto = new EmployeeDto(" ", "employeeNameSurname", LocalDate.of(2000,04,23),1L,1L);
        String error = mockMvc.perform(post(URI+"addEmployee")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(employeeDto)))
                .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
                .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json"))
                .andReturn().getResolvedException().getMessage();

        assertThat(error).isEqualTo("Cannot be empty or blank");
    }
    @Test
    void addNewEmployeeWithInvalidSurnameThrowsError() throws Exception{
        this.insertUnitAndLevel();
        EmployeeDto employeeDto = new EmployeeDto("employeeName", " ", LocalDate.of(2000,04,23),1L,1L);
        String error = mockMvc.perform(post(URI+"addEmployee")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(employeeDto)))
                .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
                .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json"))
                .andReturn().getResolvedException().getMessage();

        assertThat(error).isEqualTo("Cannot be empty or blank");
    }




    @Test
    void addingNewEmployeeWithAlreadyExistingNameSurnameAndBirthdateThrowsError() throws Exception{
        this.insertUnitAndLevel();
        EmployeeDto employeeDto = new EmployeeDto("employeeName", "employeeSurname", LocalDate.of(2000,04,23),1L,1L);
        EmployeeDto employeeDtoCopy = new EmployeeDto("employeeName", "employeeSurname", LocalDate.of(2000,04,23),1L,1L);


        mockMvc.perform(post(URI+"addEmployee")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(employeeDto)));


        String error = mockMvc.perform(post(URI+"addEmployee")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(employeeDtoCopy)))
                .andExpect(status().isConflict())
                .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json"))
                .andReturn().getResolvedException().getMessage();

        assertThat(error).isEqualTo("employee with that name, surname and date of birth already exists");
    }



    @Test
    void addingValidEmployeeWorks() throws Exception{
        this.insertUnitAndLevel();
        EmployeeDto employeeDto = new EmployeeDto("employeeName", "employeeSurname", LocalDate.of(2000,04,23),1L,1L);

        mockMvc.perform(post(URI+"addEmployee")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(employeeDto)))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType("text/plain;charset=UTF-8"))
                .andExpect(content().string("New employee added succesfully"));

    }


    private void insertUnitAndLevel() throws Exception{
        EnumerationLevel mocklevel = new EnumerationLevel("A1", "Mockdescripition");

        mockMvc.perform(post("/units/addUnit")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content("new unit"));

        mockMvc.perform(post("/levels/addLevel")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(mocklevel)));
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `MockMvcBuilders` you can create `mockMvc` object. You need to autowire the `WebApplicationContext`.

```
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext context;

@BeforeEach
void setupTests() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).build();
}
```

If you want to apply security as well then use

```
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext context;

@BeforeEach
void setupTests() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).apply(springSecurity()).build();
}
```

This will generate `MockMvc` object for each test case separately.

Comment: No I tried that, that doesn't make any difference

Comment: Please update your question with error you getting to know what is causing issue. How you running integration test parallelly?

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the db manually helped. Instantianting the mock before each was not necessary, just injecting it in the constructor and clearing the db worked. Although spring docs state to instantiate the mock as Dhaval says, that doesn't not empty the mock after use. I inject it in the constructor and use the @AutoConfigureMockMvc annotation. Then clear the db before each test and it works.

```
    @BeforeEach
    void clearDatabase(@Autowired JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        JdbcTestUtils.deleteFromTables(jdbcTemplate, "employees");
        JdbcTestUtils.deleteFromTables(jdbcTemplate, "enumerationlevels");
        JdbcTestUtils.deleteFromTables(jdbcTemplate, "units");
    }
```

Setting the jdbcTemplate as a variable and injecting it in the constructor will also work